# Internet connectivity between 2 computers

Tags: networking, network-shares, port-forwarding, iptables, connection-sharing

I have two computers

```
Comp A: 192.168.151.19
Comp B: 192.1681.151.15 (Static IP address with gateway as <comp A IP address)
```

The setup is like this

```
Internet <---->  Computer A <-------->  Computer B
```

Both computers have a single network card. The computer A is connected to the Internet. Computer B is connected to computer A via a usb-ethernet adapter.

I have tried to understand iptables and other related questions, but somehow I still not able to configure this wrongly.

I use the following iptable rules on comp A

```
   iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.151.19:443 
   iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.151.19:80 
   iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

On computer B I use the command

```
sudo ip route add default via 192.168.151.19
```

I ran `sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` on both the computers.

How can I configure this to give Internet connectivity to computer B. Also, I would like to control internet connectivity to computer B by any firewall rule that I add on computer A

Edit:
This is a repeat of an earlier question from me but with a different network setup

Comment: Why, exactly, do you have those DNAT rules?

Comment: You're missing informations: is computer B plugged to computer A with an usb-to-usb cable often seen as an ethernet usb0 card on one or both sides? Or do you have a switch or hub somewhere that you didn't mention and that connects computer A, computer B and router? I can already add that a router is between 2 networks. You're one network short, but depending on your answer the solution is a bit different